# Getting Firebase emulator error because non-existent SDK is not enabled

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to get some Firebase functions emulated locally, and have followed Google's [local emulator instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator). When I run `firebase serve` I get this error:

```
Error from emulator. FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 403, 
Mobile SDK API has not been used in project <my project ID> 
before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/overview?project=<my project ID> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

Seems straightforward, except that when I follow the [supplied URL](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/mobilesdk-pa.googleapis.com/overview) I get an error because the "Mobile SDK API" does not exist. I've tried searching on Google's API page as well and there is definitely not an API with that name.

Anybody know how I can get around this issue?

(I also tried `firebase functions:shell` and get the same error)

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that I was running an outdated version of `firebase-tools` on the CLI. Running `npm update firebase-tools` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue fixed by logging into firebase, since the error was showing on a different machine.

After running `firebase login` and the authentication process, `firebase serve` worked without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and fixed it for myself. I was running Node v11.14.0 and downgraded to the latest version of Node 8 (v 8.16.0).